# javascript accessing a member function from outer scope variable

Tags: javascript

I have been trying out some js code in jsfiddle and it seems I cant get all these combinations of codes below to work..

```
//combination #1    
function get_set() {
    this.get = function () {
        document.write("get");
    };
    this.set = function () {
        document.write("set");
    };
};

var x = get_set; // storing function reference in x
x.get(); //invoking doesnt work.

//combination#2
var get_set = function() {
    this.get = function () {
        document.write("get");
    };
    this.set = function () {
        document.write("set");
    };
};

get_set.get(); //doesnt work as well..
```

Is there something that I miss? Thanks in advance for constructive suggestion/pointing out any errors. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You either have to create a new instance of `get_set`

```
var x = new get_set();
```

or inside `get_set` you have to use `return this;` for this example to work.

Comment: The `return this` part is not good advice. If called without *new*, *this* will be the global/window object so `this.get` assigns a function to a global variable called *get* and similarly for `this.set`.

Comment: Additionaly, returning `this` from a function call doesn't create unique instances. So if `this` is returned, in `var a=get_set(), b=get_set(); b.set = 'I have changed'` `a.set` now also has the value 'I have changed'

Answer (score 3):

Your `get_set` function is a *constructor* function. It's intended to create ('construct') instances of itself. In order to make that work you need the keyword `new`. So

```
var getset = new get_set;
```

creates an instance of get_set. Now the methods `getset.set` and `getset.get` are available.

In this case maybe you could create a unique instance using an Object literal:

```
var get_set = {
    get: function () {
        document.write("get");
    },
    set: function () {
        document.write("set");
    }
};
```

Now you don't need the `new` keyword and the methods are available right away (`get_set.get`, `get_set.set`)

Comment: Perhaps, but now the OP can't make instances of *get_set*, but maybe that isn't needed anyway.

Comment: Hi RobG, it was a suggestion. I changed the wording of my answer a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Use x=new get_set; That will work.